# Does this ARIMA model take seasonality into account?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima, statsmodels

I'm writing a tutorial on traditional time series forecasting models. One key issue with ARIMA models is that they cannot model seasonal data. So, I wanted to get some seasonal data and show that the model cannot handle it.

However, it seems to model the seasonality quite easily - it peaks every 4 quarters as per the original data. What is going on?

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot

```py
from statsmodels.datasets import get_rdataset
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Get data
uk = get_rdataset('UKNonDurables', 'AER')
uk = uk.data
uk_pre1980 = uk[uk.time <= 1980]

# Make ARIMA model
order = (4, 1, 4)
# Without a seasonal component
seasonal_order = (0, 0, 0, 0)
arima = ARIMA(uk_pre1980.value, 
            order=order, 
            seasonal_order=seasonal_order, 
            trend='n')
res = arima.fit()

# Plot
all_elements = len(uk) - len(uk_pre1980)
plt.plot(uk.value, 'b', label='Actual')
plt.plot(res.forecast(steps=all_elements), 'r', label='Preds')
plt.title(f'order={order}, seasonal_order={seasonal_order}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: ARMA (and by extension ARIMA) models can capture periodicity. Seasonality is non-stationary, while periodicity is assumed stationary. So periodicity (what you observe) can be captured by non-seasonal ARIMA models (even ARMA models). This is the point IMO

Comment: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234492/what-is-the-difference-between-period-cycle-and-seasonality/234601) can be of help, although they use the terms in the reverse meaning than my previous comment

Comment: a juxtaposition of the seasonal vs periodic [here](https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/13287)

Comment: and [this](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/cyclicts/) set of definitions as well